# Twig template engine installation and create sample

Tags: php, twig

I need to know how to install php twig template and how to create a php sample using php twing template engine. I'm a beginner to twig..The documentation given in the twig site is confusing me.I need step by step instructions to install it **Windows 10**

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to define your problem much better, first which kind of installation would you like ?
Installation from the tarball downloading a zip seems not so hard.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/installation.html

Comment: I need to create sample php program using twig template engine. I have installed xampp in D directory and need to know how to install twig within xampp and how to create a sample

Answer (score 0):

Install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows) and run the following command to get the latest version:

```
composer require twig/twig
```

It will download twig. Then you can use

```
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

Comment: while installing composer the following warning is shown:

Comment: The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

Comment: You need to enable the open_ssl module in your Wamp server's php.ini File. Wamp uses 2 php.ini file. One for Apache and the other one CLI. You need to enable open_ssl extension in the second php.ini file which you can locate at `C:\wamp\bin\php\<phpversion>\php.ini`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have installed xampp in machine. Can you suggest which one is best among them? I'm very new to php and i was asked to learn and create a php sample using twig template engine.Please, Suggest me some basic sites to clearly understand the steps involved to install twig template engine

Comment: I prefer xamp too. it should be in a similar location. I don't want to do more than that, my answer is detailed enought and i put already a lot of time in it. It's your turn to put some time and effort in your research ;)